# Set CSS styling to a specific elements in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to design myself a UI in JavaFX as part of my learning process. I'm trying to use CSS to make things much easier, but I can't really grasp its concept.

What I have is a `BorderPane` with a `ToolBar` in the `top` position, and a `GridPane` in the `center` position.

My question is, how do I set styles to a group specific elements only. For example, I'm trying to set a style only specific to `Label` elements inside my `ToolBar`. I have a whole bunch of `Label`s in my window, but I'm only trying to style those inside my `ToolBar`. Is that possible?

I tried adding this code in my stylesheet:

```
.tool-bar label {
    -fx-font-family: Arial;
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
}
```

But apparently, it doesn't style any of the `Label`s at all.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Rephrased the question, since I meant that I'm targeting a group of specific nodes. Thank you to those who answered already though.

Comment: I meant that I wanted to style a group of specific nodes but not individual nodes. I'm sorry I'll rephrase the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should study tutorials: [Styling UI Controls with CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG), [Styling Layout Panes with CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/style_css.htm#JFXLY161) and the [CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) and if you still have questions include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html):

> Each node in the scene graph has an id variable, a string. This is
> analogous to the id="..." attribute that can appear HTML elements.
> Supplying a string for a node's id variable causes style properties
> for this node to be looked up using that id. Styles for specific ids
> can be specified using the "#nodeid" selector syntax in a style sheet.

Example:

```java
label.setId("customlabel");
```

CSS File:

```css
#customlabel {
    -fx-font-family: Arial;
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
}
```

To apply the same style for different nodes, you can use style classes:

> Each node in the scene graph has a styleClass variable, a
> List. This is analogous to the class="..." attribute that can
> appear on HTML elements. Supplying a string for a node's styleClass
> variable causes style properties for that style class to applied to
> this node. Styles for style classes can be specified using the
> ".styleclass" selector syntax in a style sheet. Note that a node may
> have more than one style class.

```java
node.getStyleClass().add("custom-content");
```

CSS File:

```css
.custom-content {
    -fx-font-family: Arial;
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
}
```

Comment: This is new to me. Though I wanted to see if it can be a group of nodes.

Comment: I updated my answer to include style classes @SamuelAdrianKosasih